# Symfony2 AnnotationException You have to enable OPCache or ZendOptimizer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine, opcache

I have application based on the Symfony2 framework. I have moved to the production environment, website was running fine (I was trying to adjust caching - on my hosting is xcache). But suddenly I has this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message 'You
> have to enable opcache.save_comments=1 or
> zend_optimizerplus.save_comments=1.' in
> /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/6/9/699be0da-dfbd-4651-90de-448d295bb741/playsport.sk/web/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:183
> Stack trace: #0
> /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/6/9/699be0da-dfbd-4651-90de-448d295bb741/playsport.sk/web/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php(162):
> Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException::optimizerPlusSaveComments()
>
> ## 1 /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/6/9/699be0da-dfbd-4651-90de-448d295bb741/playsport.sk/web/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(237):
>
> Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader->__construct() #2
> /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/6/9/699be0da-dfbd-4651-90de-448d295bb741/playsport.sk/web/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2103):
> appProdProjectContainer->getAnnotationReaderService() #3
> /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/6/9/699be0da-dfbd-4651-90de-448d295bb741/playsport.sk/web
> in
> /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/6/9/699be0da-dfbd-4651-90de-448d295bb741/playsport.sk/web/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php
> on line 183

I can't enable opcache.save_comments on my hosting (I don't have privileges, it's casual paid hosting service). So, I disabled all caching in prod environment and tried to rerun website. My current configuration:

web/app.php:

```
 $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
    
    // Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
    // You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
    // in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
    // also using APC.
    
    //$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
    //$xcacheLoader = new \Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\XcacheClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__) . "PlaySport", $loader);
    //$loader->unregister();
    //$xcacheLoader->register(true);
    
    
    require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
    // require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
    
    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
    //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
    
    // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
    //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

config_prod.yml:

```
    imports:
        - { resource: config.yml }
    
    #framework:
    #    validation:
    #        cache: xcache
    
    #doctrine:
    #    orm:
    #        metadata_cache_driver: xcache
    #        result_cache_driver: xcache
    #        query_cache_driver: xcache
    
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type:         fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler:      nested
            nested:
                type:  stream
                path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
            console:
                type:  console
```

I really don't know what to do. Still getting error as before. How to disable Annotation caching in Doctrine or any other solution of that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you disable the Zend OpCache and/or Zend Optimizer+ extension on your hosting ? It seems that if you disable it, you will get rid of this error since Doctrine won't do the extra check for the *opcache.save_comments* parameter.

In *\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader.php* :

```
if (extension_loaded('Zend Optimizer+') && (ini_get('zend_optimizerplus.save_comments') === "0" || ini_get('opcache.save_comments') === "0")) {
  throw AnnotationException::optimizerPlusSaveComments();
}

if (extension_loaded('Zend OPcache') && ini_get('opcache.save_comments') == 0) {
    throw AnnotationException::optimizerPlusSaveComments();
}
```

Disabling any cache won't fix this error because this check is done in the *AnnotationReader* class' constructor, which is not depending on any cache.

If you can't, you could still try to set the *opcache.save_comments* parameter to 1 with the *ini_set* PHP command.

Comment: I am using websupport.sk hosting service (best provider in Slovakia). I am not able to change opcache.save_comments trough .htaccess because of permissions (i tried it before asking question). I tried to ask the provider for solution, now i am waiting for response. But funny is, that webpage was running OK and suddenly error has appeared.

Comment: Maybe they changed their configuration recently. Did you try the trick with ini_set() ? If you can't change it with .htaccess file, I'm not sure if this would change anything, but you should still try.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved! It was caused by webhosting provider and server configuration. Opcache or Zend Optimizer was not configured properly

Comment: What was the real cause? Which configuration solved the problem?

Comment: You have to set zend_optimizerplus.save_comments or opcache.save_comments to true.

Comment: you can remove in php-fpm/conf.d symlink to opcache (if you not need that)
eg /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d - remove @10-opcache.ini ...

Comment: That's not an answer! Please edit your answer to document the exact steps or unselect the current answer. Anyone arriving here won't find this answer useful.